# Is processor can do memory and arithmetic operation at the same time?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture

In the study of assembler and processor, one thing takes me out, *how is done the instruction* :

```
add mem, 1
```

In my head, the processor cannot load the memory value **and** process the arithmetic operation during the same instruction. So I figure it takes place like:

```
mov reg, mem
add reg, 1
mov mem, reg
```

If I consider a processor with a [RISC Pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline), we can observe some stalls. It's surprising for an instruction as simple as `i++`:

```
|  Fetch  | Decode  | Exec    | Memory  | WriteB  |
          |  Fetch  |         |         | Decode  | Exec    | Memory  | WriteB  |
                    |  Fetch  |         |         |         | Decode  | Exec    | Memory  | WriteB  |
```

(As I could read in Patterson's book *Computer Architecture: A Quantative Approach*, registers are read in **Decode** uOp, Store/Load in Memory uOp and we allow ourselves to take the value of a register at the Memory uOp.)

Am I right? or the modern processors have specific methods to do that more efficiently?

Comment: It depends on how you define 'one instruction'. A CPU could execute the three steps *fetch*, *add*, *store* as separate clock cycles but all within the same single instruction. Also, a modern CPU can actually do all three operations simultaneously if the memory operand is pre-fetched into cache.

Comment: Related: [Are RMW instructions considered harmful on modern x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38034498) no. And [In x64, using "pop \[RAX\]", where is the value temporarily stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58001187) (CPUs have internal temporary storage separate from the named registers)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right, a modern x86 will decode `add dword [mem], 1` to 3 uops: a load, an ALU add, and a store.  (This is actually a simplification of various things, including Intel's micro-fusion and how AMD always keeps a load+ALU together in some parts of the pipeline...)

Those 3 *dependent* operations can't happen at the same time because the later ones have to wait for the result of the earlier one.

But execution of *independent* instructions can overlap, and modern CPUs very aggressively look for and exploit "instruction level parallelism" to run your code faster than 1 uop per clock.  See [this answer for an intro to what a single CPU core can do in parallel](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349972/how-does-a-single-thread-run-on-multiple-cores/350024#350024), with links to more stuff, like [Agner Fog's x86 microarch guide](http://agner.org/optimize/), and David Kanter's write-ups of [Sandybridge](https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/) and [Bulldozer](https://www.realworldtech.com/bulldozer/).

---

**But if you look at Intel's P6 and Sandybridge microarchitecture families, a store is actually separate store-address and store-data uops**.  The store-address uop has no dependency on the load or ALU uop, and can write the store address into the [store buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141366/can-a-speculatively-executed-cpu-branch-contain-opcodes-that-access-ram) at any time.  (Intel's optimization manual calls it the Memory Order Buffer).

To increase front-end throughput, store-address and store-data uops can decode as a micro-fused pair.  For `add`, so can the load+alu operation, so an Intel CPU can decode `add dword [rdi], 1` to 2 fused-domain uops.  (The same load+add micro-fusion works for decoding `add eax, [rdi]` to a single uop, so any of "simple" decoders can decode it, not just the "complex" decoder that can handle multi-uop instructions.  This reduces front-end bottlenecks).

This is why `add [mem], 1` is more efficient than `inc [mem]` on Intel CPUs, even though `inc reg` is just as efficient (but smaller) than `add reg,1`.  (`inc` can't micro-fuse its load+inc, which sets flags differently than `add`).  [INC instruction vs ADD 1: Does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510095/inc-instruction-vs-add-1-does-it-matter)

But this is just helping the front-end get uops into the scheduler more quickly; the load still has to run separately from the add.

But a micro-fused load doesn't have to wait for the rest of the whole instruction's inputs to be ready.   Consider an instruction like `add [rdi], eax` where RDI and EAX are both inputs to the instruction, but EAX isn't needed until the ALU add uop.  The load can execute as soon as the load-address is ready and there's a free load execution unit (AGU + cache access).  See also [How are x86 uops scheduled, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40681331/how-are-x86-uops-scheduled-exactly/).

---

> registers are read in Decode uOp, Store/Load in Memory uOp and we allow ourselves to take the value of a register at the Memory uOp

All current x86 microarchitectures use out-of-order execution with register renaming (Tomasulo's algorithm).  Instructions are renamed and issued into the out-of-order part of the core (ROB and scheduler).

The physical register file isn't read until an instruction is "dispatched" from the scheduler to an execution unit.  (Or for recently-generated inputs, forwarded from other uops.)

---

***Independent* instructions can overlap their execution**.  For example, a Skylake CPU can sustain a throughput of 4 fused-domain / 7 unfused-domain uops per clock, including 2 loads + 1 store, [in a carefully crafted loop](http://agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=415#857):

```
.loop: ; HSW: 1.12c / iter. SKL: 1.0001c
    add edx, [rsp]           ; 1 fused-domain uop:  micro-fused load+add
    mov [rax], edi           : 1 fused-domain uop:  micro-fused store-address+store-data
    blsi ebx, [rdi]          : 1 fused-domain uop:  micro-fused load+bit-manip

    dec ecx
    jnz .loop                ; 1 fused-domain uop: macro-fused dec+branch runs on port 6
```

Sandybridge-family CPUs have an L1d cache capable of 2 reads + 1 write per clock.  (Before Haswell, only 256-bit vectors could work around the AGU throughput limit, though.  See [How can cache be that fast?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/329789/how-can-cache-be-that-fast/329955#329955).)

Sandybridge-family front-end throughput is 4 fused-domain uops per clock, and they have lots of execution units in the back-end to handle various instruction mixes.  (Haswell and later have 4 integer ALUs, 2 load ports, a store-data port, and a dedicated store-AGU for simple store addressing modes.  So they can often "catch up" quickly after a cache-miss stalls execution, quickly making room in the out-of-order window to find more work to do.)

Comment: Another trick worth mentioning is skewed pipelines. These can help arithmetic operations tolerate cache access latency by adding dummy stages for arithmetic operations. In-order Intel Atom processors used skewed pipelines, but even an in-order RISC can benefit when software cannot schedule a load sufficiently early (Cell/PS3/XBox 360 PPE had such delayed arithmetic execution).