# Load/stores per cycle for recent CPU architecture generations

Tags: performance, x86, cpu, cpu-architecture, memory-bandwidth

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15657772/1593077) to

[FLOPS per cycle for sandy-bridge and haswell SSE2/AVX/AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655835/flops-per-cycle-for-sandy-bridge-and-haswell-sse2-avx-avx2)

what are the numbers of just-loads/loads-and-stores which one could issue on a core - for Sandy/Ivy Bridge, Broad/Haswell, Sky/Kaby Lake? Also interesting are the numbers of AMD Bulldozer, Jaguar and Zen.

PS - I know that might not be a sustainable rate because of cache/memory bandwidths, I'm only asking about issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on information from:

- http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/
- http://www.agner.org/optimize/
- http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=423
- https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen

| Architecture | Loads | Stores | 256-bit counts as two? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sandy/Ivy Bridge | 1 | 1 | Yes |
| Sandy/Ivy Bridge | 2 | 0 | Yes |
| Haswell/Broadwell | 2 | 1 | No |
| Skylake/Kaby Lake | 2 | 1 | No |
| Ice/Tiger Lake | 2 | 2 | No (2 store/clock sustained only for same cache line) |
| Alder Lake / Sapphire | 3 | 1 | No, but throughput may be "somewhat less" |
| Alder Lake / Sapphire | 2 | 2 | No, but throughput may be "somewhat less" |
| Bulldozer | 1 | 1 | Yes |
| Bulldozer | 2 | 0 | Yes |
| Jaguar | 1 | 1 | Yes |
| Zen 1 | 1 | 1 | Yes |
| Zen 1 | 2 | 0 | Yes |
| Zen 2 | 2 | 1 | No |
| Zen 3/4 | 3 | 2 | integer registers |
| Zen 3/4 | 2 | 1 | No, but fewer pipes handle vectors of any width |

**Sandy/Ivy**: per cycle, 2 loads, or 1 load and 1 store. 256bit loads and stores count double, but only with respect to the load or store itself - it still only has one address so the AGU becomes available again the next cycle. By mixing in some 256b operations you can still get 2x 128b loads and 1x 128b store per cycle.

**Haswell/Broadwell**: 2 loads *and* a store, and 256bit loads/stores *don't* count double. Port 7 (store AGU) can only handle *simple* address calculations (base+const, no index), complex cases will go to p2/p3 and compete with loads, simple cases may compete anyway but at least don't *have* to.

**Sky/Kaby**: the same as Broadwell

**Ice/Tiger Lake**: 2 loads and 2 stores per clock, with fully separate execution units for each (store-address uops don't run on load ports.)  2/clock stores can only be sustained if stores are to the same cache line. i.e. 1/clock write to L1d cache, but a write can commit two store-buffer entries if they're to the same line.  For memory-ordering reasons, the two store-buffer entries have to be the two oldest, so alternating stores to two separate arrays couldn't benefit from this unless you can unroll.

**Alder Lake / Sapphire Rapids**: 3 loads and 1 store, or 2 loads and 2 stores.  Agner Fog reports those throughputs for sizes up to 128-bit, but "somewhat less" for 256 and 512-bit loads/stores.  Commit to L1d may be limited like Ice Lake for more than 1 store per clock.

**Bulldozer**: 2 loads, or 1 load and 1 store. 256bit loads and stores count double.

**Jaguar**: 1 load or 1 store, and 256bit loads and stores count double. By far the worst one in this list, because it's the only low-power µarch in the list.

**Zen 1** (first-gen Ryzen): 2 loads, or 1 load and 1 store. 256bit loads and stores count double.

[**Zen 2**](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2) (Most Ryzen 3xxx and 4xxx, but there are some 3xxx models that are only Zen+ not Zen 2).
3 AGUs (2 load/store, 1 store-only).   Up to two 256-bit load operations and one 256-bit store per cycle.

[**Zen 3**](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_3): Load throughput increased from 2 to 3 for scalar integer GPRs.
Store throughput increased from 1 to 2 for scalar integer GPRs.  (Wikichip incorrectly states this as "if not 256-bit", but  https://uops.info/ testing [confirms only 1/clock](https://uops.info/html-tp/ZEN3/VMOVAPS_M128_XMM-Measurements.html) vector stores even with 128-bit `vmovaps [mem], xmm`.

**[Zen 4](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_4)**: no change from Zen 3.  AVX-512 512-bit ops are single-uop, but  occupy load and store-data units for 2 cycles each, like how Sandy/Ivy Bridge handled 256-bit load/store.  (Same for 512-bit ALU uops, single uop unlike how Zen 1 handled 256-bit.)

Comment: SnB/IvB can sustain 2x128b loads and 1x128b store per cycle, but only if they're all (or mostly) 256b.  The bottleneck is on AGUs, not on cache read-write ports.  A store-address uop can run on p2/p3 even while the load-data part of the port is still busy with the 2nd cycle of a 256b load.

Comment: Haswell doesn't have cache-bank conflicts either, according to Agner Fog.  That's only SnB/IvB.  AFAIK, HSW/BDW/SKL/KBL are all the same as far as L1D aligned load/store throughput.

Comment: Simple store-address uops don't always go to p7 on HSW+.  They can be scheduled there, but unfortunately they still get scheduled to p2/p3 and steal cycles from loads.  Intel's optimization manual quotes SKL average *sustained* L1D bandwidth as ~81B/cycle, even though peak is 96B.  This is due to those resource conflicts.

Comment: You might want to add that on recent Intel all loads or stores that cross a cache line boundary seem to count double, but other misaligned loads or stores are the same as their aligned counterparts. On AMD Ryzen the picture is much [more complex](http://fh.tl/CD).