# Why dependency in a loop iteration can't be executed together with the previous one

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, micro-optimization, micro-architecture

I use this code to test the impact of dependency in a loop iteration on IvyBridge:

```
global _start
_start:
    mov rcx,    1000000000
.for_loop:          
    inc rax     ; uop A
    inc rax     ; uop B
    dec rcx     ; uop C
    jnz .for_loop   

    xor rdi,    rdi
    mov rax,    60  ; _exit(0)
    syscall
```

Since `dec` and `jnz` will be macro-fused to a single uop, there are 3 uops in my loop, they are labeled in the comments.

uop B depends on uop A, so I think the execution would be like this:

```
A C
B A C  ; the previous B and current A can be in the same cycle
B A C
...
B A C
B
```

Therefore the loop can be executed 1 cycle per iter.

However, the `perf` tool shows:

```
 2,009,704,779      cycles                
 1,008,054,984      stalled-cycles-frontend   #   50.16% frontend cycles idl
```

So it's 2 cycle per iter, and there are 50% frontend cycle idle.

What caused the frontend 50% idle? Why the hypothetical execution diagram can't be realized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**B and A form a loop-carried dependency chain**.  *A* in the next iteration can't run until it has the result of *B* in the previous.

**Any given *B* can never run in the same cycle as an *A*: what input would the later one use, if the earlier one hasn't produced a result yet?**

This chain is 2 cycles long (per iteration), because the latency of `inc` is 1 cycle.  This creates a latency bottleneck in the back-end that out-of-order execution can't hide.  (Except for very low iteration counts where it can overlap it with code after the loop).

Just like if you fully unrolled a huge chain of `times 102400 inc eax`, there's no instruction-level parallelism for the CPU to find between a chain of instructions that each depend on the previous.

The macro-fused `dec rcx/jnz` uop is independent of the RAX chain, and is a shorter chain (only 1 cycle per iteration, being only 1 dec&branch uop with 1c latency).  So it can run in parallel with B or A uops.

---

See [my answer on another question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349972/how-does-a-single-thread-run-on-multiple-cores/350024#350024) for more about the concept of **instruction-level parallelism** and dependency chains, and how CPUs exploit that parallelism to run instruction in parallel *when they're independent*.

[Agner Fog's](https://agner.org/optimize/) microarch PDF shows this with examples in an early chapter: *Chapter 2: Out-of-order execution (All processors except P1,
PMMX)*.

---

**If you started a new 2-cycle dep chain every iteration, it would run as you expect**.  A new chain forking off every iteration would expose instruction-level parallelism for the CPU to keep *A* and *B* from different iterations in flight at the same time.

```
.for_loop:
    xor eax,eax          ; dependency-breaking for RAX
    inc rax     ; uop A
    inc rax     ; uop B
    dec rcx     ; uop C
    jnz .for_loop
```

Sandybridge-family handles xor-zeroing without an execution unit, so this is still only 3 unfused-domain uops in the loop, so IvyBridge has enough ALU execution ports to run all 3 in a single cycle.  This also maxes out the front-end at 4 fused-domain uops per clock.

Or if you changed A to start a new dep chain in RAX with any instruction that unconditionally overwrites RAX without depending on the result of the `inc`, you'd be fine.

```
    lea  rax, [rdx + rdx]     ; no dependency on B from last iter
    inc  rax                  ; uop B
```

Except for a couple instructions with an unfortunate output dependency: [Why does breaking the "output dependency" of LZCNT matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390165/why-does-breaking-the-output-dependency-of-lzcnt-matter/)

```
    popcnt rax, rdx        ; false dependency on RAX, 3 cycle latency
    inc  rax               ; uop B
```

On Intel CPUs, only `popcnt`, and `lzcnt/tzcnt` have an output dependency for no reason.  It's because they use the same execution unit as `bsf`/`bsr`, which leave the destination unmodified if the input is zero, on Intel and AMD CPUs.  Intel still only documents it on paper as undefined if the input is zero for [BSF](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BSR.html)/[BSR](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BSR.html), but they build hardware that implements stronger guarantees.  (AMD does even document this BSF/BSR behaviour.)  Anyway, so Intel's BSF/BSR are like CMOV, and need the destination as an input in case the source reg is 0.  `popcnt`, (and lzcnt/tzcnt on pre-Skylake) suffer from this, too.

---

If you made the loop more than 5 fused-domain uops, SnB/IvB could issue it at best 1 per 2 cycles from the front-end.  Haswell and later "unroll" in the loop buffer or something so a 5 uop loop can run at ~1.25 c per iteration, but SnB/IvB don't.  [Is performance reduced when executing loops whose uop count is not a multiple of processor width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311872/is-performance-reduced-when-executing-loops-whose-uop-count-is-not-a-multiple-of/53148682#53148682)

The front-end issue/rename stage is 4 fused-domain uops wide in Intel CPUs since Core 2.

Comment: Ah... I'm dumb, I made a logical error by overlooking the simplest fact that the next uop A depends on the previous uop B. So it's a loop-carried dependency.

Comment: Something interesting: If I change the 2 `inc`s to `lea rax, [rbx+1] | mov rbx, rax`, then it can run 1 cycle per iter, though it's also a loop-carried chain with length 2. Perhaps the processor is smart enough to figure out the second `mov` doesn't really depend on the first `lea`?

Comment: @user10865622: IvyBridge has move-elimination: zero-latency `mov reg,reg` for 32 and 64-bit registers, and for xmm/ymm regs.  (And for `movzx r32, r8`).  [Can x86's MOV really be "free"? Why can't I reproduce this at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44169342)/.  There is a true dependency there, IDK what you mean by "doesn't really depend on the LEA", unless you mean that `mov` is so trivial it could be handled special (which is exactly what IvB and later do).  If you used any other instruction, like `lea ebx, [rax]`, you'd have a 2 cycle dep chain.

Comment: That's surprising, I've never heard about zero-latency move. Because I don't know the detail so I can only guess the processor might just replace the second `mov rbx, rax` to `lea rbx, [rbx+1]` to remove the dependency. Turns out my guess is wrong.

Comment: @user10865622: oh, yeah the mechanism is handling `mov` in the issue/rename stage with register renaming instead of an execution unit, not fusing mov with other instructions in the decoders.  Go read Agner Fog's uarch guide for SnB/IvB.  It's only a few pages, *much* shorter than Intel's whole optimization manual (which is big but often unclear about what applies to which uarch, and isn't always updated for later uarches.)  Then when you see a weird effect, maybe you'll remember something Agner mentioned and can go re-read that section for details.

Comment: @user10865622: I added a section showing what happens if you break the loop-carried dep chain so every iteration starts a new chain.

Comment: Thanks, I've also followed your suggestion to read the whole chapter of IvyBridge in Agner's book, the elimination of `mov` and `xor eax, eax` is really mentioned in that chapter. Though frankly that chapter has very high information density, some sections are difficult to absorb.

Comment: @user10865622: yeah, you'll be going "oh *that* makes sense now" while you play around with stuff for a long time after reading it.  But yeah, any time you find a mystery, check Agner's uarch guide an instruction tables.  e.g. the `mov r,r` entry for IvB shows 0 to 1 cycle latency, and has a note "may be elimin." which would have pointed you in the right direction for something to search on.  And finally, Agner's stuff does have some mistakes / omissions, unfortunately.  And typos in his instruction tables, like an occasional `5` instead of `0.5` in at least one Ryzen entry; use  common sense.