# Why does using the "register" keyword makes my code faster?

Tags: c, x86, cpu-registers

I am learning/re-learning C, and I've learnt about the *register* keyword. On many websites, people said it is recommended to not be used, or even useless. The book I am using says it is useful in for-loops, then I tried without the keyword:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int count = 1;

    clock_t start = clock();
    while(count != 0) {
        count++;
    }
    clock_t stop = clock();
    double time = (double)(stop - start);

    printf("%f", time);

    return 0;
}
```

and, then with it:

```
[..] register int count = 1; [...]
```

Compiling the source code with GCC, I have seen that using *register* made the program around 5x faster.

Hence, my question, is there something wrong with me (e.g. my GCC) or is the *register* keyword actually useful?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248362/discussion-on-question-by-schilive-why-does-using-the-register-keyword-makes-m).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if signed overflow is undefined behavior, binaries **do** have a definitive behavior. So we can check why using `register` makes the code faster.

Using an undefined behavior with no optimizations means that GCC can produce a completely different assembly even for small, apparently insignificant, modifications.
`register` is such insignificant modification since it's an historical micro-optimization that GCC doesn't honor anymore (apparently).
Quoting the GNU C Manual Reference:

> **20.10 auto and register**
> For historical reasons, you can write `auto` or `register` before a local variable
> declaration. `auto` merely emphasizes that the variable isn’t static; it changes
> nothing.
> `register` suggests to the compiler storing this variable in a register. How-
> ever, GNU C ignores this suggestion, since it can choose the best variables
> to store in registers without any hints.

However, the two binaries differ exactly in the fact that `count` is held in a register (`ebx` specifically) vs a local variable (and in the fact that a frame pointer is created).

[image: Left: binary without register. Right: binary with register]

So `register` does indeed makes your code faster. You can see, on the left, that without it (at `-O0` optimization level) GCC generated `add [rbp+count], 1` (this is a 32-bit increment, IDA doesn't show that) while with the `register` modifier `add ebx, 1` was generated.
[The 5x slow-down seems to match the store-load forwarding latency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274355/cycles-cost-for-l1-cache-hit-vs-register-on-x86).

Note however that GCC may move `count` to a register or in memory at its will (unless maybe with `volatile`), this can happen if you change `int` to `unsigned int` or to `unsigned long long` or if too many other local variables are in use or with any other compiler switch (like specific optimizations).

`register` had the desired effect in this simple code because there were no other constraints in place from the compiler analysis.
It's however interesting to see that GCC doesn't completely ignore it like Stallman claims in his manual.

Comment: *GNU C ignores this suggestion, since it can choose the best variables to store in registers without any hints.* - That's assuming optimization is enabled, which it always should be for any code where performance is relevant at all.  But that was not the case here, so it's not applicable.  Instead, this is basically a duplicate of [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394)

Comment: @PeterCordes Why? GCC could be made to choose to ignore `register` at any optimization level. In fact, it could ignore `register` at the parsing layer. Truth is, it just doesn't ignore it, it ignores whatever weight `register` add to its internal register allocating heuristic if optimizations are enabled. This is different than ignoring the keyword.

Comment: Yeah, interesting point.  It needs to reject C that takes the address of a `register` variable, and print a diagnostic.  IIRC, a diagnostic is requires about ill-formed programs like that.  Since it already has to know the variable can't have an address, it makes some sense to make asm where that's true.  I haven't checked what it does when there are so many `register` vars that there aren't enough registers; I'd guess the first n get regs, later are just like non-`register` locals.  Also, it already has to parse it to some degree for stuff like `register int foo asm("r8")`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has undefined behavior because you rely on `count` becoming `0` by incrementation, which may occur as a side effect of signed arithmetic overflow, but is not defined.

You could modify your test by defining `count` as an `unsigned int` as `unsigned int` arithmetics is defined as computed modulo `UINT_MAX+1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int count = 1;

    clock_t start = clock();
    while(count != 0) {
        count++;
    }
    clock_t stop = clock();
    double time = (double)(stop - start);

    printf("%f\n", time);

    return 0;
}
```

Yet the above code executes instantly when compiled with optimisations because the compiler can determine that no side effect occurs during the 4294967295 iterations leading to `count == 0`. Adding a `register` keyword does not change that.

Compiling with optimisations disabled gives a different result for **gcc** as can be observed on [Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/o186aWz9P). Without the `register` keyword, the variable `count` is stored in memory within the stack frame, whereas it is indeed stored in register `%ebx` when the `register` keyword is used, leading to a much faster execution time. This probably explains the the behavior you observe, but be aware that **clang** for example does not do that: variable `count` is stored in the stack frame memory in both cases.

Using the `register` keyword may have an impact on the code generation under special circumstances, but modern compilers generally ignore it and choose which variables to store in registers and when much more efficiently than the programmer would. Here are my recommendations:

- don't use `register`
- do use compiler optimisations for production builds
- your book is probably outdated, try and use a more recent one.

Comment: You may be right about the age of the book: I suspect it is from 1996.