# measure cycles spent in accessing remote cache

Tags: multithreading, shared-memory, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

How to measure cycles spent in accessing shared remote cache say L3. I need to get this cache access information both system-wide and for per-thread. Is there any specific tool/hardware requirements. Or can I use any formula to get an approximate value of cycles spent over a time interval

Comment: That's somewhat of the wrong question to ask. Accessing cache is often overlapped with other things. So the # of cycles spent accessing cache may or may not mean anything.

Comment: @Mysticial i need to know whether different threads' cache access to l3 is degrading the performance. How else can it be calculated

Comment: You can only guess at it. Profilers will give you big-picture aggregate numbers. Then compare them with the results of other apps with different memory patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the **average**  latencies (when a single thread is running) to various caches present on your machine, you can use memory profiler tools such as RMMA for windows (http://cpu.rightmark.org/products/rmma.shtml) and Lmbench for linux.

You can also write your own benchmarks based on the ideas used by these tools.
See the answers posted on this StackOverflow question: 
[measuring latencies of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603995/measuring-latencies-of-memory)
Or Google for how the Lmbench benchmark works.

If you want to find exact latencies for particular memory access patterns, you will need to use a simulator. This way you can trace a memory access as it flows through the memory system. However simulators will not model all the effects that are present in a modern processor or memory system.

If you want to learn how multiple threads affect the average latency to L3, I think the best bet would be to write your own benchmark.

Comment: Does this profiling extensively need Harware Performance Counters