# How does lmbench measure L1 and L2 cache latencies using C? (cannot understand explanation in manual)

Tags: c, linux, pointers, caching, benchmarking

I am trying to understand how lmbench measures latency for L1, L2 and main memory.

The [man page](http://www.bitmover.com/lmbench/lat_mem_rd.8.html) for lat_mem_rd mentions the method, but it's not clear to me:

> The benchmark runs as two nested loops. The outer loop is the stride
>   size. The inner loop is the array size. For each array size, the
>   benchmark creates a ring of pointers that point forward one stride.
>   Traversing the array is done by
>
> p = (char **)*p;
>
> in a for loop (the over head of the for loop is not significant; the
>   loop is an unrolled loop 1000 loads long). The loop stops after doing
>   a million loads.

How do you "create a ring of pointers that point forward one stride" ? Wouldn't this mean that if the stride size was 128 Bytes, you would need to make a linked list with each node separated by exactly 128 Bytes from it's previous one? malloc just returns some random free piece of memory, so I don't see how that's possible in C.
And in the piece of code, I would always get a segmentation fault. (tested it, and what is p supposed to be initialized with?)

There is a similar thread on SO([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603995/measuring-latencies-of-memory)) and the first answer discusses this, but it does not talk about how strided approach can be used with linked lists. I also looked at the source code itself (lat_mem_rd.c) but couldn't understand this from that either.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can allocate large chunk of memory and then arrange elements of the linked list within allocated block on any boundary you want.

Comment: If the actual allocated memory is in contiguous array, then I can iterate over it in strides and don't even need a linked list. (like if stride is 8 bytes, I can access every other element in integer array). As this is the most easiest and obvious way, and lmbench is not using it, it must be because it does not work (not enough to fool the prefetchers?). Any ideas?

Comment: If you just iterate in stride in a continuous array on modern Intel CPUs, hardware prefetcher will kick in and will start speculatively fetching data from memory ahead of CPU issuing instructions requiring that data. In addition CPU itself will figure that there's no dependency between elements and will be able to issue multiple instructions to fetch independent chunks of data in parallel. Ideally you want next element to fetch to depend on data of current element. This would make sure that hardware under the hood has no chance to get too smart. Linked list does the job.

Comment: Hmm...makes sense. That answers my question. Thanks :)