# Approximate latency to access caches and main memory via QPI (dual socket/processor)

Tags: performance, caching, memory, intel, latency

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087280/approximate-cost-to-access-various-caches-and-main-memory) has a good list of times that it takes to access various parts of the computer architecture in a uniprocessor environment. How about in a dual processor environment, over Intel's QPI bus?

Let's assume a 64 byte packet memory is allocated on the first CPU. The second CPU has to access this via a 8.0 GT/s QPI bus, so I know the serialization latency alone is 4~ ns. What additional latency should I expect on the QPI bus?

Comment: Did the first CPU modify the line? does it still reside in its L1/L2 caches?

Comment: @Leeor Hm, I'd like to hear the latency for both cases.