# How to perform an On-the-Fly encoding of a stream of still-pictures (video) for sending these from C# to Python?

Tags: c#, python, compression, kinect, zeromq

I'm getting both Depth & Color frames from the Kinect 2, using the Kinect SDK ( `C#` ), and I'm sending them to Python clients using **`ZeroMQ`**.

```
this.shorts     = new ushort[ 217088]; //  512 *  424
this.depthBytes = new   Byte[ 434176]; //  512 *  424 * 2
this.colorBytes = new   Byte[4147200]; // 1920 * 1080 * 4

public void SendDepthFrame(DepthFrame depthFrame)
    {
        depthFrame.CopyFrameDataToArray(this.shorts);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(shorts, 0, this.depthBytes, 0, this.depthBytes.Length);
        this.depthPublisher.SendByteArray(this.depthBytes);
    }

public void SendColorFrame(ColorFrame colorFrame, WriteableBitmap map)
    {
        colorFrame.CopyRawFrameDataToArray(this.colorBytes);
        this.colorPublisher.SendByteArray(this.colorBytes);
    }
```

Since I'm sending uncompressed data, **I'm overloading the network** and I'd like to compress these frames.

### Is this possible for a continuous stream-processing?

I know that I can do that by compressing in a `PNG/JPEG` format, but I would like to maintain the notion of video stream.

The goal is to send the compressed data in `C#`, and then decoding them in Python.

> Is there any libs that allow to do that ?

Comment: **What transport-class** do you use for ZeroMQ and **how many clients** do you distribute the frame-data to and **what is your target FPS** to meet ? Design shall follow some quantitative metrics, verifiable in a PoC, before any code starts to get typed.

Comment: Currently I'm using tcp, but I'll probably switch to udp. I distribute data to 1 or 2 clients. Around 25 fps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### May forget about compression for the moment and downscale for `PoC`

If your design indeed makes sense, try to focus rather on core **`CV`**-functionality first, at a cost of reduced ( downscaled ) FPS, colordepth, resolution ( in this order of priority ).

Your indicated data produces about 1 Gbps exgress data-stream, where the forthcoming  `CV`-processing will choke anyways, having remarkable **`CV`**-process performance ( delay / latency ) / interim data-representations' memory-management bottlenecks.

This said, the `PoC` may benefit from 1/4 - 1/10 slower FPS acquisition/stream-processing and the finetuned solution may show you, **how many nanoseconds-per-frame** does your code have in stream-processing margin ( to finally decide **if** there is **time & processing-power** enough to include any sort of `CODEC`-processing into the otherwise working pipeline )

[image]

> <kbd>check the lower-left window **delays in `[usec]`**</kbd> by a right-click -> [Open in a New Tab]
> to see enlarged and realise a scale / order of magnitude of a few actual **`openCV`** procesing latencies of about a 1/4 of your one **`FullFD`** still image in a real-world processing with much smaller `FPS` on a single-threaded `i7`/**`3.33 GHz`** device, where L3 cache sizes can carry as much as **`15 MB`** of imagery-data with fastest latencies of less than **`13 ns ( core-local access case ) .. 40 ns ( core-remote NUMA access case )`** + block-nature of the `CV`-orchestrated image-processing benefits a lot from minimal if not zero cache-miss-rate -- but this is not a universal deployment hardware scenario to rely on:
>   [image]
> [The costs ( <kbd>**`penalty`**</kbd> ) **of each cache-miss** and a need to ask for and peform an access to data in the main `DDR-RAM` is about `+100 ns` >>> https://stackoverflow.com/a/33065382/3666197](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33065382/3666197)

**Without a working pipeline**, there are no quantitative data about the sustained stream-processing / it's margin-per-frame to decide the `CODEC`-dilemma a-priori of the proposed `PoC`-implementation.

Comment: Well, I reduced the frame because in the end i don't really need to get 25 FPS, so I'm around 15/17 right now and it's "ok". Now when I'm streaming both color & depth images, I'm sending at 250 Mbps.