# How to improve my concurrent processing time in this code?

Tags: python, concurrent-processing

I have programmed the following code in Python:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, \
                               ThreadPoolExecutor,   \
                               as_completed
import random
import time

def addS(v):
    s=0
    start=time.time()
    for i in range(0,len(v)):
        s=s+v[i]
    start1=time.time()
    print ("sec time ",start1-start," sum is ",s)

def dummyFun(l):
    s=0
    for i in range(0,len(l)):
        s=s+l[i]
    return s

def main():
    workers=4
    v = [random.randint(1,101) for _ in range(1000000)]
    addS(v)
    dim=(int)(len(v)/(workers*10))
    s=0
        
    chunks=(v[k:k+dim] for k in range(0,len(v),(int)(len(v)/(workers*10))))
    start=time.time()
   
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        futures=[executor.submit(dummyFun,chunk) for chunk in chunks]
    
    start1=time.time()

    for future in as_completed(futures):
        s=s+future.result()
    print ("concurrent time ",start1-start," sum is ",s)
```

when I use the `ProcessPoolExecutor()` my results are the following:

```
       sec time  0.06529831886291504  sum is  51004089
concurrent time  0.5757372379302979   sum is  51004089
```

I have also changed to `ThreadPoolExecutor()` and the results are:

```
       sec time  0.06471061706542969  sum is  50981197
concurrent time  0.09298276901245117  sum is  50981197
```

Also, when I set up `max_workers` parameter as `None`, I got the following results:

```
       sec time  0.06425285339355469  sum is  50983899
concurrent time  0.09010934829711914  sum is  50983899
```

How can I improve my concurrent time? because the sequential time keeps being faster all the time or is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"How can I improve my concurrent time?"*

Avoid all process-instantiation costs and use memory-I/O efficient vectorised code for the rest, best combined with `numpy`-broadcasting

```
s = np.random.randint( 1, 101, size = 1_000_000, dtype = np.int8 ).sum()
```

where hardware AVX-performance can outweight any other, software-only, tricks.

For testing, it is fair to first and always pre-set **`np.random.seed( seed = someHausNumero )`** otherwise all tests cease to be repeatable, providing each time different results, which a serious, repeatable science never wants, does it?

:o)

---

> *<sub>thanks @user3666197, but I was dubious why my sequential time is shorter than the concurrent version? maybe it is because the list operations are optimized in Python? – Little [13 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65098045/how-to-improve-my-concurrent-processing-time-in-this-code/65098556?noredirect=1#comment115089089_65098556)</sub>*

Having a small amount of items ( `1E6` is a small foot-print of the data ), process-instantiations and similar `...PoolExecutor()`-overheads introduce more costs than a split-work will ever be able to repay to at least a break-even state ( not paying more than ever getting back ). Try the same with off-cache, memory-I/O more intensive sizes, well above say `1E10+` bytes ( given you have RAM / swap-space enough, sure )

While the problem above is a *"just"*-`[ CONCURRENT ]` orchestration of the flow of processing-tasks, you may like to read a few details on add-on overhead costs and atomicity-of-work, that both influence the maximum practically achievable speedup, compared to a pure-`[ SERIAL ]` (or sequential ) flow of work  >>> https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3

The nature of the add-on costs is the same - parameters need SER/comms/DES + results need SER/comms/DES and all that comes at memory-allocation add-on costs and memory-I/O costs - for which see this >>> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087280/approximate-cost-to-access-various-caches-and-main-memory/33065382?r=SearchResults&s=2|0.0000#33065382](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087280/approximate-cost-to-access-various-caches-and-main-memory/33065382?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C0.0000#33065382)

Comment: thanks @user3666197, but I was dubious why my sequential time is shorter than the concurrent version? maybe it is because the list operations are optimized in Python?

Comment: Having a small amount of items ( 1E6 is a small foot-print of the data ), process-instantiations and similar ...PoolExecutor()-overheads introduce more costs than a split-work will ever be able to repay to at least a break-even state ( not paying more than ever getting back ). Try the same with off-cache, memory-I/O more intensive sizes, well above say 1E10+ bytes ( given you have RAM / swap-space enough, sure )