# How to stop system from crashing during RandomForest training? Will decreasing the number of workers do some good?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, joblib

For 140K of NLP data, there will be huge number of features at hand.

So increasing the number of trees from 200 to 350 led to instance crash with [`n_jobs` = 7 | parallel jobs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-n_jobs) in a 8 CPU-cores machine. I just want to know if it works like a `Pool()` and demands memory? If I decrease the cores to 3 or 5, will it be useful?

**Any ways for preventing memory crash**?

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer = lambda x: x.split(' '), min_df = min_df, ngram_range = (1,rng))),
    ('clf',RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = n_estimators, class_weight = class_weight, criterion = criterion, min_samples_split = min_samples_split,
                           max_features = max_features, oob_score = oob_score, warm_start = warm_start,
                           n_jobs = 7, random_state = SEED)),
    ])

    del train, test
    gc.collect()
    
    pipeline.fit(train_x, train_y)
    acc = accuracy_score(pipeline.predict(test_x), test_y)
    print(acc, top_n(pipeline,test_x,test_y))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **Q :** Any ways for preventing memory crash ?

**A :**
Sure,
similar work-experience since Win-XP crashing Py2.7 `n_jobs` in the very same direction.

Solution :

**Step 1 :**
profile the RAM-allocation envelope for having a single `n_jobs = 1` set in the otherwise same settings ( one can create, even inside Python-interpreter a `SIGNAL`-based automated memory monitor / recorder to indeed profile real-virtual-...-memory usage, strobing for any raw or coarse time-quanta in doing so & logging all such data or just a moving-window maximums - this goes beyond the scope of this post, yet one may reuse my other posts on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bjoblib%5D%20is%3Aanswer) and use Python-`signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1,...)`-tools for the hand-made "monitor-n-logger" )

**Step 2 :**
having obtained the RAM-allocation & virtual memory usage, from visual inspection or from hard-data collected in Step 1, try to spawn as many `n_jobs` that fit the physical RAM (minus one, if you use the host for other work, during the such `RandomForrestPREDICTOR.fit()`-computing - my use-case was using a pool of dedicated, headless hosts for `.fit()`-training cavalry of predictor models on many machines in embarrasingly parallel orchestration, each having 100% CPU-usage and zero-memory-I/O swaps for about 30+ hours to meet the large-scale re-training & model selection deadlines )

This said, CPU-usage is not your main enemy here, the RAM-efficient computing is.

Your graph shows :
- **swap**-thrashing did not start ( good )
- cpu-**hopping** did start at a cost of decreasing the cpu-cache data re-use, once a job was moved away, data previously kept in LRU-cache needs to get re-fetched from RAM, which is about 1,000x slower, than if sourcing them from cpu-core local L1d-[cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087280/approximate-cost-to-access-various-caches-and-main-memory/33065382#33065382) ( thermal throttling on big workloads make cpu-cores hot and the hardware starts to moving jobs from one core to another (hopefully a cooler one))
- cpu workloads are not as hell-hard as they could be (in some even harder number-crunching), as `RandomForestPREDICTOR`-s are moving and crawling through all the `[M,N]`-sized ( N being the number of examples in a sub-set elected for the `.fit()`-training, yet still "long" ) data, during the computation, which gives cpu some time to rest, while waiting for next part of data being fed in. So there are times, where CPU-core is not harnessed to its 100% capacity )