# Is 'malloc' possibly a bottleneck in my program?

Tags: c, performance, malloc

My program calls `malloc` 10'000 times a second. I have absolutely no idea how long a malloc call takes.

- As long as an uncontested mutex lock? (10-100 ns)
- As long as compressing 1kb of data? (1-10 us)
- As long as an SSD random read? (100-1000 us)
- As long as a network transfer to Amsterdam? (10-100ms)

Instead of spending two hours to investigate this, only to find out that it is absolutely dwarfed by some other thing my program does, I would like to get a rough idea of what to expect. Ballpark. Not precise. Off by factor 10 does not matter at all.

The following picture was updooted 200 times [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087280/approximate-cost-to-access-various-caches-and-main-memory?noredirect=1&lq=1):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To state the obvious first: profiling for *specific* use cases is always required. However, this question asked for a *rough general ballpark approximation guesstimate of the order of magnitude*. That's something we do when we don't know if we should even think about a problem. Do I need to worry about my data being in cache when it is then sent to Amsterdam? Looking at the picture in the question, the answer is a resounding No. Yes, it could be a problem, but only if you messed up big. We assume that case to be ruled out and instead discuss the problem in probabilistic generality.

It may be ironic that the question arose when I was working on a program that cares very much about small details, where a performance difference of a few percent translates into millions of CPU hours. Profiling suggested malloc was not an issue, but before dismissing it outright, I wanted to sanity check: Is it theoretically plausible that malloc is a bottleneck?

As repeatedly suggested in a closed, earlier version of the question, there are large differences between environments.
I tried various machines (intel: i7 8700K, i5 5670, some early gen mobile i7 in a laptop; AMD: Ryzen 4300G, Ryzen 3900X), various OS (windows 10, debian, ubuntu) and compilers (gcc, clang-14, cygwin-g++, msvc; no debug builds).

I've used this to get an idea about the characteristics(*), using just 1 thread:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const size_t allocs = 10;
    const size_t repeats = 10000;
    printf("chunk\tms\tM1/s\tGB/s\tcheck\n");
    
    for (size_t size = 16; size < 10 * 1000 * 1000; size *= 2) {
        float t0 = (float)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        size_t check = 0;
        
        for (size_t repeat = 0; repeat < repeats; ++repeat) {
            char* ps[allocs];
            for (size_t i = 0; i < allocs; i++) {
                ps[i] = malloc(size);
                if (!ps[i]) {
                    exit(1);
                }
                for (size_t touch = 0; touch < size; touch += 512) {
                    ps[i][touch] = 1;
                }
            }
            for (size_t i = 0; i < allocs; i++) {
                check += ps[i][0];
                free(ps[i]);
            }
        }
        
        float dt = (float)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC - t0;
        printf ("%d\t%1.5f\t%7.3f\t%7.1f\t%d\n",
            size,
            dt / allocs / repeats * 1000,
            allocs / dt * repeats / 1000 / 1000,
            allocs / dt * repeats * size / 1024 / 1024 / 1024,
            check);
    }
}
```

The variance is stark, but, as expected, the values still belong to the same ballpark.
the following table is representative, others were off by less than factor 10

```
chunk   ms      M1/s    GB/s    check
16      0.00003  38.052     0.6 100000
32      0.00003  37.736     1.1 100000
64      0.00003  37.651     2.2 100000
128     0.00004  24.931     3.0 100000
256     0.00004  26.991     6.4 100000
512     0.00004  26.427    12.6 100000
1024    0.00004  24.814    23.7 100000
2048    0.00007  15.256    29.1 100000
4096    0.00007  14.633    55.8 100000
8192    0.00008  12.940    98.7 100000
16384   0.00066   1.511    23.1 100000
32768   0.00271   0.369    11.3 100000
65536   0.00707   0.141     8.6 100000
131072  0.01594   0.063     7.7 100000
262144  0.04401   0.023     5.5 100000
524288  0.11226   0.009     4.3 100000
1048576 0.25546   0.004     3.8 100000
2097152 0.52395   0.002     3.7 100000
4194304 0.80179   0.001     4.9 100000
8388608 1.78242   0.001     4.4 100000
```

Here's one from a 3900X on cygwin-g++. You can clearly see the larger CPU cache, and after that, the higher memory throughput.

```
chunk   ms      M1/s    GB/s    check
16      0.00004  25.000     0.4 100000
32      0.00005  20.000     0.6 100000
64      0.00004  25.000     1.5 100000
128     0.00004  25.000     3.0 100000
256     0.00004  25.000     6.0 100000
512     0.00005  20.000     9.5 100000
1024    0.00004  25.000    23.8 100000
2048    0.00005  20.000    38.1 100000
4096    0.00005  20.000    76.3 100000
8192    0.00010  10.000    76.3 100000
16384   0.00015   6.667   101.7 100000
32768   0.00077   1.299    39.6 100000
65536   0.00039   2.564   156.5 100000
131072  0.00067   1.493   182.2 100000
262144  0.00093   1.075   262.5 100000
524288  0.02679   0.037    18.2 100000
1048576 0.14183   0.007     6.9 100000
2097152 0.26805   0.004     7.3 100000
4194304 0.51644   0.002     7.6 100000
8388608 1.01604   0.001     7.7 100000
```

So what gives?
With small chunk sizes, >= 10 million of calls per second are possible even on old commodity hardware.
Once sizes go beyond CPU cache, i.e. 1 to 100-ish MB, RAM access quickly dominates this (I did not test malloc without actually using the chunks).
Depending on what sizes you malloc, one or the other will be the (ballpark) limit.
However, with something like 10k allocs per second, this is something you can likely ignore for the time being.

Comment: this is surely going to have a lot to do with the memory paging sizes on various systems. Once you start demanding large chunks, new pages are going to have to be allocated, mapped, etc for almost every malloc call. Small ones can be satisfied within a page

Comment: theres a good book written by web server team where they track down perf issue and eventually end up writing their own heap manager that get what they know is a large enough lump at the start of each request via malloc but then they manage it from then on, wish I could remeber the name of it

Comment: @pm100 Funnily enough the malloc calls in question are such big-chunk requests by my custom heap manager. This replaced billions of smaller mallocs and improved the runtime significantly.

Comment: Yet another parameter you could vary in your experiments is the malloc library itself; take a look at `mimalloc` and `jemalloc`, for example.