# Can .NET 6's Parallel.ForEachAsync be nested?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, .net-6.0, parallel.foreachasync

I want to do calculations with an outer and an inner loop which I can do in parallel.
Furthermore, I want to use the [async/await-based programming model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model). In the outer loop there is a place where a resource is needed which can only be used by one thread.

I thought of implementing the loops using [`ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-parallel-foreachasync-1(system-collections-generic-iasyncenumerable((-0))-system-threading-tasks-paralleloptions-system-func((-0-system-threading-cancellationtoken-system-threading-tasks-valuetask)))) and restrict the access to the resource using [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-6.0):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
                    
public class Program {
    private static Dictionary<int,IReadOnlyList<int>> resource = new();
    private static SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new(1);
    
    public static async Task Main() {       
        var outerLoopSource = Enumerable.Range(0,10);
        await Parallel.ForEachAsync(outerLoopSource, OuterLoopFunction);
        foreach(var (key, list) in resource)
            Console.WriteLine(key+": "+string.Join(',', list));
    }
                                    
    public static async ValueTask OuterLoopFunction(int i, CancellationToken cancel) {
        // some time consuming calculation ...      
        var key = i%3;
        const int listSize = 10;
        IReadOnlyList<int> list;
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try {
            if(!resource.TryGetValue(key, out list)) {
                var newList = new int[listSize];
                list = newList;
                resource.Add(key, list);
                await Parallel.ForEachAsync(Enumerable.Range(0,listSize), InnerLoopFunction);
                ValueTask InnerLoopFunction(int j, CancellationToken cancel) {
                    // some time consuming calculation ...
                    newList[j] = 42+i;
                    return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
                }
            }
        } finally {
            semaphore.Release();
        }           
        // do something with list
    }   
}
```

[Example in fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0RV5fA)

Can `ForEachAsync` be used in nested loops like this and is the number of operations in parallel still restricted by `System.Environment.ProcessorCount`?

#### Update

In the comments people suggested to use [dataflow components from the Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library). That might be the better approach if I wrote the code from scratch. However, in my case there is quite a lot of legacy code doing the calculations and it seems to me I would have to restructure it significantly in order to apply the concept, since I would have to  lift what is currently the inner loop on the same level as the outer loop. Hence I wonder if using annother SemaphoreSlim to restrict the number of parallel executions as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66635760/5525302) avoids running to many tasks/threads in parallel without too much performance penalty.

Comment: Use an `ActionBlock` instead. Instead of looping, create a pipeline of steps using eg TransformBlock instances. What does your code actually do, once you remove the attempts to parallelize/restrict threads?

Comment: `Parallel.ForEachAsync` is meant to execute asynchronous operations concurrently with data that comes either from an `IEnumerable` or `IAsyncEnumerable`. There's no attempt to partition or batch like `Parallel.ForEach`. The default is to use the number of cores but that can usually be increased because asynchronous operations are usually just waiting for IO to complete.

Comment: On the other hand, ActionBlock and the other classes in TPL Dataflow are used to create a pipeline of blocks, similar to a script pipeline. Each block processes an input message and passes the result to the next block down the line. Most blocks have input/output buffers. By default one task is used per block, but that can be changed. This means you can use a TransformBlock to crawl web pages and emit URLs using eg 1 task, and have another block download and process those URLs using 10 tasks.

Comment: Yes, I can be nested, and will be restricted by your threadpool but about if it will perform better or not is quite complicated to say. It depends of how compute-intensive your "//some time consuming calculation" is.
Check my answer in this thread 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71434976/why-isnt-parallel-for-fast-with-heap-intensive-operations/71452625#71452625
And this Microsoft Documentation about parallelism
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-in-data-and-task-parallelism

Comment: I would reconsider your design. Using async/await is not really great fit for compute-bound operations. I'm also skeptical of holding locks while doing compute bound operations, as far as I can tell, you should be able get rid of the lock, replacing it with a concurrentDictionary. I would either use something like Dataflow, or possibly as two sequential parallel loops.

Comment: Does ConcurrentDictionary implement locking more efficient?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not falling into the trap of [Over parallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-in-data-and-task-parallelism#avoid-over-parallelization)? Have you performed measurements when both are parallel and when only the outer one?

Comment: @PeterCsala: In the original legacy code, just the inner loop was done in parallel using Parallel.ForEach. I do not want to omit this, since the outer loop may process only one element and the user might experience a performance loss in that case.

Answer (score 1):

No, the [`ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) affects only the degree of parallelism of the configured `Parallel.ForEachAsync` loop. It's not an ambient property that affects all other parallel loops that might be nested inside the outer parallel loop. For example if you configure the outer parallel loop with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5`, and the inner parallel loop with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3`, the delegate of the inner parallel loop might be invoked concurrently 15 times (5 * 3) at any given moment.

This assuming that the inner parallel loop is unrestricted. In your example you have enclosed the inner parallel loop in a protected region, by using a `SemaphoreSlim(1)`. So only one inner parallel loop can be active at any given moment. The maximum number of concurrent invocations of the inner loop's delegate is `Environment.ProcessorCount` (the default `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` for the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` API).