# await Parallel.ForEachAsync in recursive function

Tags: c#, recursion, concurrency, asp.net-core-6.0, parallel.foreachasync

I have recursive function for tree.
Can I loop children node with `Parallel.ForEachAsync`?

```
private async Task<List<ResponseBase<BatchRowData>>> SaveDepartments(DepartmentTree node,
    string parentUnitGuid, List<ResponseBase<BatchRowData>> allResponses)
{
    if (parentUnitGuid == null)
    {
        return allResponses;
    }
    await Parallel.ForEachAsync(node.children, async (child, cancellationToken) =>
    {
        ResponseBase<BatchRowData> response = new ResponseBase<BatchRowData>();
        //...do something 
        Unit unit = new Unit();
        unit.SerialNum = child.data.DepartmentNumber;
        unit.UnitName = child.data.DepartmentName;
        unit.ParentUnitGuid = parentUnitGuid;
        string unitGuid = await DBGate.PostAsync<string>("organization/SaveUnit", unit);
        if (unitGuid != null)
        {
            response.IsSuccess = true;
            response.ResponseData.ReturnGuid = unitGuid;
            await SaveDepartments(child, unitGuid, allResponses);
        }
        else
        {
            response.IsSuccess = false;
            response.ResponseData.ErrorDescription = "Failed to Save";
        }
        allResponses.Add(response);
    });
    return allResponses;
}
```

It works. but I wonder if the tree order levels is always saved with `Parallel.ForEachAsync`.
Because in my tree. it must be.
Or I should use simple sync `foreach`?

My application is ASP.NET Core 6.0.

Comment: Have you tried  `SemaphoreSlim` as @Theodor Zoulias mentioned, it creates concurrent thread and block waiting for the semaphore. [`You can get the details here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-7.0#examples)

Comment: Related: [Can .NET 6's Parallel.ForEachAsync be nested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71513038/can-net-6s-parallel-foreachasync-be-nested)

Comment: Also somewhat related: [Parallel tree traversal in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099703/parallel-tree-traversal-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

First things first, the [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1#thread-safety) collection is not thread-safe, so you should synchronize the threads that are trying to `Add` to the list:

```
lock (allResponses) allResponses.Add(response);
```

Otherwise the behavior of your program is undefined.

Now regarding the validity of calling the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) recursively, it doesn't endanger the correctness of your program, but it does present the challenge of how to control the degree of parallelism. In general when you parallelize an operation you want to be able to limit the degree of parallelism, because over-parallelizing can be harmful for both the client and the server. You don't want to exhaust the memory, the CPU or the network bandwidth of either end.

The [`ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) property limits the parallelism of a specific `Parallel.ForEachAsync` loop. It does not have recursive effect. So you can't depend on this.

The easier way to solve this problem is to use a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) as the throttler, and enclose the `body` of the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` loop in a `try`/`finally` block:

```
await semaphore.WaitAsync();
try
{
    // The body
}
finally { semaphore.Release(); }
```

The semaphore should be initialized with the desirable maximum parallelism for both of its arguments. For example if the desirable limit is 5 then:

```
SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new(5, 5);
```

Another way of solving this problem would be to have a single non-recursive `Parallel.ForEachAsync` loop, which is fed with the items of a [`Channel<(DepartmentTree, string)>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1), and inside the body of the loop you write the children of each department in the channel. This should be more efficient than nesting multiple `Parallel.ForEachAsync` loops the one inside the other, but it is also more complex to implement, and more prone to programming errors (bugs). So I'll leave it out from this answer.