# How fast (or slow) is a LDR cache HIT compared to other ARM instructions

Tags: arm, arm64, cpu-cache

The newer ARM Architecture Reference Manuals don't give instruction timings any more. (Instruction timings *were* given, at least for the early ARM2 and ARM3 chips).

I know that cache misses result in external memory accesses that are *very* slow, compared with, say, data instructions like ADD x0, x1, x2 or BIC x0, x1, x2.

But how fast is a L1 cache hit?

If the answer is "it depends ..." what would be a rough guess (ballpark) figure?

Cache enabled (obviously). "Flat" memory mapping (ie. virtual address = physical address).

I suppose the answer also depends on the precise hardware being used. And that one should simply write test cases and *measure* the specific timings one's interested in...

I'm interested in the ARMv8 Raspberry Pi models -- which I don't possess. (I'm using QEMU).

I'd also be interested in any other timings, say, relative to:

```
ADD x0, xzr, xzr         ; == 1

ADD d0, d1, d2           ; floating-point

LDR x0, [x2]             ; L1 cache hit
LDR x0, [x2]             ; L1 cache miss, L2 cache hit
LDR x0, [x2]             ; L1 cache miss, L2 cache miss

LDP x0, x1, [x2]         ; L1 cache hit
LDP x0, x1, [x2]         ; L1 cache miss, L2 cache hit
LDP x0, x1, [x2]         ; L1 cache miss, L2 cache miss
```

Basically, what I *really* want to know is "when is it faster to load a value from memory rather than compute it? (on a Raspberry Pi 4B)"

There's the page [Approximate cost to access various caches and main memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087280/approximate-cost-to-access-various-caches-and-main-memory) but that refers to Intel chips.

Answer (score 0):

I found https://developer.arm.com/documentation/uan0016/a/ from which it appears that a LDR from L1-cache has latency 4 and throughput 1. While a basic ALU op has latency 1 and throughput 2.