The low utilization of multi-GPUs in single-program multiple-data (SPMD) by implementing the auto parallelization in JAX

I try to use 4 GPUs to solve a Physic-informed neural networks (PINN) problem. And I find that when I use one GPU, the utilization of GPU can reach 100% and the training speed is high (200 [it/s]), but when I use 4 GPUs by implementing sharding and jax.jit strategies as shown in this

I shard all my data to different GPUs and replicate the parameters and state of function as shown in guidelines of auto parallelization. And I find my 4 GPUs utilization are quite low, as shown before 10%, and the training speed is quite low (20 [it/s]).
I am curious about the reason. I know there is an alternative method for a parallelisation of computing my model, such as jax.sharp_map or jax.pmap. But I try the method of jax.pmap, mentioned in this.
For example:
import functools

# Remember that the 'G' is just an arbitrary string label used
#          to later tell 'jax.lax.pmean' which axis to reduce over.
# Here, we call it
#          'G', but could have used anything,
#          so long as 'pmean' used the same.

@functools.partial(jax.pmap, axis_name='G')
def update(params: Params, x: jnp.ndarray, y: jnp.ndarray):
    # Compute the gradients on the given minibatch (individually on each device)
    loss, grads = jax.value_and_grad(loss_fn)(params, x, y)

    # Combine the gradient across all devices (by taking their mean)
    grads = jax.lax.pmean(grads, axis_name='G')

    # Also combine the loss. Unnecessary for the update, but useful for logging
    loss = jax.lax.pmean(loss, axis_name='G')

    # Each device performs its own update, but since we start with the same params
    # and synchronise gradients, the params stay in sync
    LEARNING_RATE = 1e-3
    new_params = jax.tree_map(
       lambda param, g: param - g * LEARNING_RATE, params, grads)
    return new_params, loss

The same problem shows up. That is my GPUs utilization and training speed are both low.
Do you have any ideas about my issue?

It may help to learn the actual costs, code has to pay (in time) to use any piece of data inside GPU's own SM Register ~ 25 [ns], SM own L1-cache ~ 35 [ns] but ~200-300+ [ns] if using data from texture cache or ~300-700 [ns] for data from global MEM. Going for a data away off your own-GPU takes even way longer: HostToDev / DevToHost xfer latencies were about ~10'000-12'000 [ns] "expensive". GPU-s are designed as latency-masking devices for (using small amounts of) local (near) data. See how many clk-cycles a code waits ( ie by other SM-warped threads can "mask" by running in the meantime )

See details on actual latency costs paid "inside" GPU ( time-maps - how "far" in time actual data are on GPU and how many warp-cycles can mask one such "far"-or-"near" in time data-fetch ) in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087280/approximate-cost-to-access-various-caches-and-main-memory/33065382#33065382 Values are for Fermi at 1G14 [Hz], yet principle of GPU latency-masking ( best for many threads remaining in non-divergent code-paths, so as to keep the warps "smoothly scheduled", not fallen into greedy mode ) architectures remains the same.
