What exactly is slowing np.sum down?
It is known that np.sum(arr) is quite a lot slower  than arr.sum().  For example:
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(7)
A = np.random.random(1000)
%timeit np.sum(A)
2.94 µs ± 13.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
%timeit A.sum()
1.8 µs ± 40.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

Can anyone give a detailed code-based explanation of what np.sum(arr) is doing that arr.sum() is not?
The difference is insignificant for much longer arrays. But it is relatively significant for arrays of length 1000 or less, for example.
In my code I do millions of array sums so the difference is particularly significant.

Over here, the difference seems to stay fairly constant irrespective of the size of the input. Seems like some extra dispatching overhead in the generic function, as opposed to a straight method call on the NDArray?

Last I checked, I think the __array_function__ dispatching machinery was responsible for most of it. Dunno if that's still the case.

Given the sizes and given the known mechanics of how the CPU-cache hierarchy works, it would be fair to explicitly evict all the "generation"-phase data away from cache-hits, so as to indeed "measure" something representative in the very next ( falsely enjoying cache-hits for data still in contemporary large L1/L2-L3-caches ( unless explicitly LRU-policy manually "evicted" away by some "safely" larger B=np.random.random( 1E9 ) )

Could you reproduce the same ( order-independent and cache-independent ) measurements as commented in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78626515/what-exactly-is-slowing-np-sum-down#comment138620701_78626563

1 µs difference is typical of what I see when comparing numpy functions and methods. (not just sum).

@hpaulj yes. I just really wanted to know what is causing it here at the code level.

When I run np.sum(a) in debug mode on my PC, it steps into the following code.
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.5/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L2178
The following is the part of the code where it is relevant.
import numpy as np
import types


def _wrapreduction(obj, ufunc, method, axis, dtype, out, **kwargs):
    passkwargs = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items()
                  if v is not np._NoValue}

    if type(obj) is not np.ndarray:
        raise NotImplementedError

    return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)


def copied_np_sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=np._NoValue, initial=np._NoValue, where=np._NoValue):
    if isinstance(a, types.GeneratorType):
        raise NotImplementedError

    return _wrapreduction(
        a, np.add, 'sum', axis, dtype, out, keepdims=keepdims,
        initial=initial, where=where
    )

Note that this ends up calling np.add.reduce(a).
Benchmark:
import timeit


def benchmark(setup, stmt, repeat, number):
    print(f"{stmt:16}: {min(timeit.repeat(setup=setup, stmt=stmt, globals=globals(), repeat=repeat, number=number)) / number}")


n_item = 10 ** 3
n_loop = 1000
n_set = 1000

data_setup = f"""\
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
a = rng.random({n_item})
"""

benchmark(setup=data_setup, stmt="np.sum(a)", repeat=n_set, number=n_loop)
benchmark(setup=data_setup, stmt="a.sum()", repeat=n_set, number=n_loop)
benchmark(setup=data_setup, stmt="copied_np_sum(a)", repeat=n_set, number=n_loop)
benchmark(setup=data_setup, stmt="np.add.reduce(a)", repeat=n_set, number=n_loop)

np.sum(a)       : 2.6407251134514808e-06
a.sum()         : 1.3474803417921066e-06
copied_np_sum(a): 2.50667380169034e-06
np.add.reduce(a): 1.195137854665518e-06

As you can see, copied_np_sum performs similarly to np.sum, and np.add.reduce is similar to a.sum.
So the majority of the difference between np.sum and a.sum is likely due to what copied_np_sum does before calling np.add.reduce.
In other words, it's the overhead caused by the dict comprehension and the additional function calls.
However, although there is a significant difference in the above benchmark that reproduces the OP's one, as pointed out in the comment, this may be overstated.
Because timeit repeatedly executes the code and uses the (best of) average, with a small array like in this benchmark, the array may already be in the CPU cache when it is measured.
This is not necessarily an unfair condition. The same thing could happen in actual use. Rather, it should be so whenever possible.
That being said, for a canonical answer, we should measure it.
Based on @user3666197 advice, we can create a large array immediately after creating a to evicts a from the cache.
Note that I decided to use np.arange here, which I confirmed has the same effect but runs faster.
import timeit


def benchmark(setup, stmt, repeat, number):
    print(f"{stmt:16}: {min(timeit.repeat(setup=setup, stmt=stmt, globals=globals(), repeat=repeat, number=number)) / number}")


n_item = 10 ** 3
n_loop = 1
n_set = 100

data_setup = f"""\
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
a = rng.random({n_item})
_ = np.arange(10 ** 9, dtype=np.uint8)  # To evict `a` from the CPU cache.
"""

benchmark(setup=data_setup, stmt="np.sum(a)", repeat=n_set, number=n_loop)
benchmark(setup=data_setup, stmt="a.sum()", repeat=n_set, number=n_loop)
benchmark(setup=data_setup, stmt="copied_np_sum(a)", repeat=n_set, number=n_loop)
benchmark(setup=data_setup, stmt="np.add.reduce(a)", repeat=n_set, number=n_loop)

Without eviction (With cache):
np.sum(a)       : 2.6407251134514808e-06
a.sum()         : 1.3474803417921066e-06
copied_np_sum(a): 2.50667380169034e-06
np.add.reduce(a): 1.195137854665518e-06

With eviction (Without cache):
np.sum(a)       : 4.916824400424957e-05
a.sum()         : 3.245798870921135e-05
copied_np_sum(a): 4.7205016016960144e-05
np.add.reduce(a): 3.0195806175470352e-05

Naturally, the presence or absence of cache makes a huge impact on performance.
However, although the difference has become smaller, it can still be said to be a significant difference.
Also, since these four relationships remain the same as before, the conclusion also remains the same.
There are a few things I should add.
Note1
The claim regarding method loading is incorrect.
benchmark(setup=f"{data_setup}f = np.sum", stmt="f(a)", repeat=n_set, number=n_loop)
benchmark(setup=f"{data_setup}f = a.sum", stmt="f()", repeat=n_set, number=n_loop)

np.sum(a)       : 4.916824400424957e-05
a.sum()         : 3.245798870921135e-05
f(a)            : 4.6479981392621994e-05  <-- Same as np.sum.
f()             : 3.27317975461483e-05    <-- Same as a.sum.
np.add.reduce(a): 3.0195806175470352e-05  <-- Also, note that this one is fast.

Note2
As all benchmarks show, np.add.reduce is the fastest (least overhead). If your actual application also deals only with 1D arrays, and such a small difference is important to you, you should consider using np.add.reduce.
Note3
Actually, numba may be the fastest in this case.
from numba import njit
import numpy as np
import math


@njit(cache=True)
def nb_numpy_sum(a):
    # This will be a reduce sum.
    return np.sum(a)


@njit(cache=True)
def nb_pairwise_sum(a):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation
    N = 2
    if len(a) <= N:
        return np.sum(a)  # reduce sum
    else:
        m = len(a) // 2
        return nb_pairwise_sum(a[:m]) + nb_pairwise_sum(a[m:])


@njit(cache=True)
def nb_kahan_sum(a):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm
    total = a.dtype.type(0.0)
    c = total
    for i in range(len(a)):
        y = a[i] - c
        t = total + y
        c = (t - total) - y
        total = t
    return total


def test():
    candidates = [
        ("np.sum", np.sum),
        ("math.fsum", math.fsum),
        ("nb_numpy_sum", nb_numpy_sum),
        ("nb_pairwise_sum", nb_pairwise_sum),
        ("nb_kahan_sum", nb_kahan_sum),
    ]

    n = 10 ** 7 + 1
    a = np.full(n, 0.1, dtype=np.float64)
    for name, f in candidates:
        print(f"{name:16}: {f(a)}")


test()

Accuracy:
np.sum          : 1000000.0999999782
math.fsum       : 1000000.1000000001
nb_numpy_sum    : 1000000.0998389754
nb_pairwise_sum : 1000000.1
nb_kahan_sum    : 1000000.1000000001

Timing:
np.sum(a)         : 4.7777313739061356e-05
a.sum()           : 3.219071435928345e-05
np.add.reduce(a)  : 2.9000919312238693e-05
nb_numpy_sum(a)   : 1.0361894965171814e-05
nb_pairwise_sum(a): 1.4733988791704178e-05
nb_kahan_sum(a)   : 1.2937933206558228e-05

Note that although nb_pairwise_sum and nb_kahan_sum have mathematical accuracy comparable to NumPy, neither is intended to be an exact replica of NumPy's implementation.
So there is no guarantee that the results will be exactly the same as NumPy's.
It should also be clarified that this difference is due to the amount of overhead, and NumPy is significantly faster for large arrays (e.g. >10000).

The following section was added after this answer was accepted. Below is an improved version of @JérômeRichard's pairwise sum that sacrifices some accuracy for faster performance on larger arrays. See the comments for more details.
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

# Very fast function which should be inlined by LLVM.
# The loop should be completely unrolled and designed so the SLP-vectorizer 
# could emit SIMD instructions, though in practice it does not...
@nb.njit(cache=True)
def nb_sum_x16(a):
    v1 = a[0]
    v2 = a[1]
    for i in range(2, 16, 2):
        v1 += a[i]
        v2 += a[i+1]
    return v1 + v2

@nb.njit(cache=True)
def nb_pairwise_sum(a):
    n = len(a)
    m = n // 2

    # Trivial case for tiny arrays
    if n < 16:
        return sum(a[:m]) + sum(a[m:])

    # Computation of a chunk (of 16~256 items) using an iterative 
    # implementation so to reduce the overhead of function calls.
    if n <= 256:
        v = nb_sum_x16(a[0:16])
        i = 16
        # Main loop iterating on blocks (of exactly 16 items)
        while i + 15 < n:
            v += nb_sum_x16(a[i:i+16])
            i += 16
        return v + sum(a[i:])

    # OPTIONAL OPTIMIZATION: only for array with 1_000~100_000 items
    # Same logic than above but with bigger chunks
    # It is meant to reduce branch prediction issues with small 
    # chunks by splitting them in equal size.
    if n <= 4096:
        v = nb_pairwise_sum(a[:256])
        i = 256
        while i + 255 < n:
            v += nb_pairwise_sum(a[i:i+256])
            i += 256
        return v + nb_pairwise_sum(a[i:])

    return nb_pairwise_sum(a[:m]) + nb_pairwise_sum(a[m:])


Could you, please, adapt your benchmark code so as to be fair and not to re-use data still held inside CPU-caches from its own generation phase? Manual "eviction" from L1/L2/L3-caches ( In 2024-Q2 being way above 1E7 bytes large ) is simple and necessary not to comparing apples to oranges ( as results claim tens of [ns] for 1k data-elements, that actually ought be well beyond ~100-300+ [ns] far, just to fetch a very first byte from RAM )

@user3666197 Thanks for the advice. How do I perform a manual eviction in this case? Should I just run it with number=1?

No, never, that way you'd loose all the plasticity of "population"-of-results. Try it like (a) putting "_ = np.random.random( int( 1E9 ) )" between your "a = ...;" & "f = ..." commands in setup-string, or even (b) putting "_ = np.random.default_rng( 0 ).random( int( 1E9 ) ); ..." into stmt-string (+later, after collecting durations data for several repetitions of such test, subtract similarly timed (as set to be reproducible) duration of such 1E9-large "cache-sweeping"-array generation (received from testing just the generation of the sweeper data alone),(c) sub a pair of time.monotonic_ns()

@user3666197 Thank you again for the advice. I re-ran the test using option (a). The results are added to my post. In order to save time, I decided to use an array size of 1GB and use arange instead of random. As expected, the performance changed significantly, but the problem still reproduced and my conclusion remains the same :)

Is it clear if numba is implementing exactly the same summation method? I worry about numerical accuracy.

@Simd numba uses a reduce sum, while numpy uses a pairwise sum. So the results will not be the same.

( + 1 ) Glad you found it reasonably helpful - you might like a more global picture on actual latency costs ( as these matter both in low-latency and HPC designs ), that if not curated can damage parallel-programing ( or vectorised-syntax use ) due to added costs to the expected speedups from the Amdahl's Law ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087280/approximate-cost-to-access-various-caches-and-main-memory/33065382#33065382

@Simd I added pairwise sum and kahan sum to the numba examples (because I was curious). And found that it's still faster than numpy for small arrays.

@ken that's a great addition. Isn't Kahan summation meant to be more accurate than pairwise summation? Also, would the pairwise summation function be faster if it was iterative rather than recursive?

Interesting! But why do you use np.zeros to create variables? Numba allocations are often quite slow. Here for a scalar it is not so bad but it still add a non-negligible overhead. To make the Numba function a bit faster you can use 2 accumulators. To make the pair-wise function faster, you can use larger chunks since recursive calls are expensive (especially compared to a simple addition). Something like 8 or 16 seems better. AFAIR, Numpy already does that (so it is not strictly a pair-wise summation). For medium/big array, the two Numba implementation are clearly sub-optimal.

@Simd Yes, Kahan is more accurate in general but not always in specific use-cases. The complexity of the error is O(log n) versus O(1) but the complexity does not matter much for small arrays due to hidden constant/factors. Also O(log n) is already very good for all n relatively small so the pair-wise is generally a good trade-off between performance and accuracy and this is why Numpy use it (the naive sum is really not accurate : O(n) error and O(n**0.5) in average AFAIR). For n<100 the difference between the 3 methods should be very small (same with n<1000 for the 2 firsts).

@Simd Yes, an iterative is more efficient but it also make the code bigger / more complex. Increasing the chunk size is sometimes enough to reduce the function call overhead though writing an iterative version is a bit better. A common approach is to do a SIMD-friendly chunk-based naive reduction (with small chunks) followed by an accurate sum (pair-wise or kahan). This gives much better performance (mitigate the overhead of the accurate method) while providing a similar accuracy (just few ULPs of additional error which is negligible in nearly all cases). SIMD also helps for accuracy.

Oh and btw I think it is worth noting that fastmath=True break the Kahan sum so one should never use this compilation flag on a Kahan sum (it makes it as accurate as the naive sum, that is not accurate, while being certainly slower).

@JeromeRichard I would love to see a faster version which is still very accurate but can it be done in numba?

@Simd Here is a rather fast pair-wise implementation in Numba. It uses a 16-way reduction with 3-level tail-call optimization. Its accuracy should be similar to Numpy if not even slightly better. It outperforms Numpy on all arrays with <100_000 items on my machine. On array with 1_000~10_000 items, it is like 2~3 times faster. On smaller ones, it is 4-5 times faster. For arrays of size <1000, the optional optimization can be removed without a significant performance loss (while being simpler).

@Simd Note that Numba does not generate (packed) SIMD instructions but scalar ones in this case (without fastmath=True). This is because of an open issue (I reported few years ago but still not fixed) in an optimization pass called SLP-vectoriser. Numpy does not use (packed) SIMD instructions either (for sake of simplicity). This is a bit sad because it would be up to 4 times faster on mainstream x86 CPUs in your case. A lower language is needed to do this optimization (or to speed up a lot the Kahan sum which will always be slower than the optimized pair-wise code).

Do you have a link to the bug report?

@Simd It is this one. The pattern is the same : the unrolling of the inner-loop prevent the SIMD vectorization, but AFAIK this is the role of the SLP vectorizer to do that (and an analysis of the assembly code show that instructions are not shuffled so the optimization seems possible)... AFAIK, the GNU toolchain can does such optimization. Note I use Numba 58.1 (last available version on my machine) which may do not use the last version of LLVM though (but newer Numba versions seem to still use LLVM 14 released 2 years ago).

@Simd Just one more note: I just found out that the overhead of Numba calls is >50% of the time for arrays with <1000 items (300 ns), so SIMD instructions are actually not the main bottleneck in this case... The function is so fast, that you should avoid calling it from CPython ;) !

@JérômeRichard I get 170ns for @nb.njit(cache=True)
def add(a, b):
return a + b

@JérômeRichard I tried a.dtype.type(0) and failed (I thought), so I changed my approach, but it seems I must have done something wrong... I updated my code to use a.dtype.type(0). BTW, The code you posted on pastebin is excellent and could benefit many people. Would you consider posting it as an answer or allowing me to include it in my answer? I'm concerned about potential licensing issues and the risk of it becoming inaccessible in the future.

@ken  for speed and accuracy I get : https://bpa.st/IGMA  xsum is doing exact arithmetic so is the correct answer.  This particular sum seems to suit nb_numpy_sum  but  others don't so much in terms of accuracy.

Here is another set of accuracy tests https://bpa.st/W66Q. In this case only math.fsum is completely accurate and nb_numpy_sum is least accurate.

It is not surprising that there are cases where the pairwise sum is worse than the reduce sum. For example, [0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1] is another case where the reduce sum is better than the pairwise sum (N=2). Also, according to Wikipedia, there is an enhanced version of Kahan sum that can handle additions with such large differences in absolute values.

The enhanced version is nb_neumaier_sum in the timings I pasted. What I don't understand is why the "faster" pairwise sum isn't actually faster.  Is it faster for you?

@Simd This is very surprising you get better performance with the neumaier sum than the kahan sum, and not speed up for the alternative pair-wise implementation. The fact that all method have a similar execution time make me thing most of the time is overhead and not the actual computational time. Does this time exclude the compilation time? Caching can also introduce some overhead: is this faster without caching?

@Simd Regarding accuracy, the neumaier sum is generally better when the standard deviation of your array is quite big. An alternative solution is to sort data but this is generally more expensive (except on GPU or certainly on CPU with AVX-512 too). If this is not the case, then, generally, applications should not require operations to be so precise and it is often better to change the algorithm so errors does not accumulate thanks to more numerically-stable algorithms. At least, it was the case on all numerical simulation I worked on so far. An error of few ULP should never be an issue.

@ken You can include the code in your question ;) (since it does not directly answer the initial question and I do not have much more to add to it I guess). Maybe you can remove the optional part of the shared code to make it simpler/shorter since your answer is already quite big.

@Simd The "faster" version is faster on my PC. It's not surprising that the size 4096 and below is faster because it's basically a reduce sum, but the faster version is competitive with np.sum up to 10**5 elements, while the N=2 pairwise is barely competitive up to 10**4. Beyond that, np.sum is faster, but unlike the N=2 pairwise, which is more than 10 times slower, it's only a few percent slower. So it's not that helpful for your specific case, but it might be helpful for others.

@JérômeRichard Thank you! I'll leave it as it is without omitting anything. Since the display size of the code block is fixed, the downside of losing information would be greater, I think.

The difference only occurs for small enough arrays, and is really negligible (but significant).

If you look at the bytecode, np.sum(A) must fetch the method from the module, which might contribute a tiny bit to the small delay.
# np.sum(A)
  6           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (np)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (sum)
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (A)
              6 CALL_METHOD              1
              8 RETURN_VALUE

# A.sum()
  9           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (A)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              0 (sum)
              4 CALL_METHOD              0
              6 RETURN_VALUE

In addition, there is also a slightly different route to reach the code that actually performs the computation (for example np.sum checks that the input is not a generator, etc.), which adds a different overhead, but in fine the algorithm/code used is the same. numpy.ndarray.sum actually refers to numpy.sum in the documentation.
If you run a profiler on both codes, you can see the difference lies in fromnumeric.py (see @ken's answer that also discusses this):
import cProfile

A = np.array([1])

cProfile.run('np.sum(A)')

#          10 function calls in 0.000 seconds

#    Ordered by: standard name

#    ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
#         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
#         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:2172(_sum_dispatcher)
#         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:2177(sum)
#         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:71(_wrapreduction)
#         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fromnumeric.py:72(<dictcomp>)
#         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.exec}
#         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
#         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
#         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
#         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}


cProfile.run('A.sum()')

#          6 function calls in 0.000 seconds

#    Ordered by: standard name

#    ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
#         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
#         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _methods.py:47(_sum)
#         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.exec}
#         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
#         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
#         1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'sum' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}

Interestingly, there is the same difference when starting from a list:


You are right that is only true for arrays that are not very long. The difference is signifant for arrays of length 1000 or less, for example.

@Simd yes it's significant (there is always a difference), but negligible (it's a very short time)

There might be some extra checks as well in np.sum before actually performing the operation. My point is it's just overhead, not a fundamental difference in algorithm. And actually the documentation for np.narray.sum refers to np.sum.

My code does millions of these sums so it makes a big difference.

Is the "advantage" reproducible even if test-data pre-fetched ( and still camping in ) L1/L2/L3-caches got manually evicted by something like running a mandatory noise-generator _ = np.random.random( 1E9 ) before each timed section?

@Simd in this case I agree, this is important, but do you always use the same array? Creating an array also takes time so you have to see the whole picture.

@user3666197 good question, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to test this ;)

Good joke ;) Mare Tranquilitatis, over & out
