Does it make sense to use Python's multiprocessing module when deploying code on Azure?
Our team has deployed a Python script on Azure Machine Learning (AML) to process files stored on an Azure storage account.
Our pipeline consists of a ForEach activity, that calls the Python script for each or the listed files. Running it from the Azure Data Factory (ADF) triggers multiple individual pipelines that run concurrently. I am not using the expression in parallel because I am unsure how these individual jobs are assigned across the different vCPUs.
In addition to the "parallelization" managed by AML, would it make sense to parallelize the processing at the Python level using Python's multiprocessing module?
I gave it a shot using the following approach, but it did not appear to reduce the overall processing time.
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Pool

[...]

mp_processes = 2
if mp_processes is True :
    p = Pool(int(mp_processes))
    output1, output2 = zip(*p.map(process, process_queue))

[...]


Given hardware and software properties of the code-execution ecosystem, shared resources will never perform better than dedicated hardware with zero background workloads. This said, you should also read about the add-on costs, the multiprocessing "infrastructure" ( copies of Python interpreter process instantiated first - yes, add-on overhead + increased RAM-footprints, reduced cache-hit efficiencies explode data access-time by 10x ~ 100x, etc )

Details why are here : https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/5 plus here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087280/approximate-cost-to-access-various-caches-and-main-memory/33065382#33065382

Thanks for your quick reply @user3666197. I will review these SO posts.
