# Are 64-byte CPU cache line reads aligned on 64-byte boundaries?

Tags: caching, cpu, memory-alignment, cpu-cache

CPU [cache lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_entries) are typically 64-bytes. When a CPU (say modern Intel processor) reads a cache line from memory, does the CPU read from 64-byte aligned blocks of memory, or any contiguous 64-byte block? What is the alignment behavior?

In other words, does the CPU only read blocks starting at addresses where the low 6 bits are zero? Or another/any alignment?

Comment: Yes, cache lines are aligned by their size, so an address can be separated into byte-offset-within-line (low 6 bits) vs. the rest.  See https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf / [How much of ‘What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory’ is still valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47714514) (most of it, including the basics like this.)

Comment: Duplicate of [Cache line and memory address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71015334) .  I guess I should answer one or the other instead of just in comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do cache lines work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928995/how-do-cache-lines-work)

Answer (score 0):

The processor's memory subsystem will load an entire cache-aligned block of memory when any location within that block is read, if the the address maps to a cacheable location in the address space (e.g. ordinary RAM).
If the read is of more than one byte and crosses a cacheline boundary, more than one cacheline can be read from external memory. For example, a read of a 16 bit short int starting at the last byte in a cacheline will cause two whole cachelines to be read from external memory.