# Cache miss penalty: how much data can be loaded from RAM at once?

Tags: memory, x86, cpu, cpu-cache

I'm working with big maps (golang) and dicts (python) and just wondering how much data a RAM write/read can be done at once?

So for example when I'm iterating through a 10GB dict, would each cache miss result in just fetching a DWORD(or how wide is the typical RAM access?) from RAM or will x86/kernel load a batch of related data to L3 (or queueing a set of load instructions to memory controller)?

In both cases, wouldn't processing big data structures be bottlenecked by RAM access latency? (+all the refresh cycles the memory controller has to deal with)

Comment: A whole cache line, 64 bytes, for normal memory access (not special regions marked uncacheable).  And no, unless you have a linked list or tree, out-of-order exec can generate the next load address while a previous cache miss is still in flight.  (memory level parallelism is very important for modern CPUs.)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate of [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8126311), but reading that will answer your question.  Ah, found a more specific duplicate: [How do cache lines work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3928995)